# Can't make deb files work using Theos. Manually copying the dylib - works

Tags: iphone, cydia, deb, tweak

I'm having a really weird problem. I've developed my first tweak for the iPhone (intended for Cydia distribution). I'm all done developing the tweak and everything works, but I'm having trouble packing it into a deb file. Typing make and manually copying the dylib into Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries and the preference file into Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences - everything works just fine, but when I type make package, my tweak doesn't work at all. The files are copied to their right folders, I can see the settings in the Settings.app, but the dylib won't run, I can't even see my NSLog in the console. I tried using dpkg -b, and even http://www.myrepospace.com/iDeb/ but to no avail.
What can I do? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of Theos, and you posted this question in the IRC channel and then summarily left.
I would like to help you, but I need to look at the package that Theos creates.

Barring the usual issues, since it IS a tweak, please make sure to respring after you install the package, as dpkg will not do that for you.

You can find me in #theos (irc.saurik.com) as DHowett.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (and theos too, it's awesome although it could use more documentation, but that's for another day).
I actually found my problem and it was due to wrong formatting of the Makefile.